# Vuerouter : need to import, but how to avoid circular dependency?

Tags: vue.js, circular-dependency, vue-router

I try to find a solution to a problem of circular dependency.
In my Vuejs application, I want a function `makeUrl(url)` which computes an absolute url of the given parameter by adding the $router.base value at the beginning.

So I put this in my modules `routes.js` :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    base: '/subdirectory',
    //...
});

function makeUrl(url){
    return router.base + url;
}

export {makeUrl};
export default router;
```

`routes.js` is imported in `main.js`, the entry point of my application, where I create my Vue main instance.

In `routes.js` I import my page components, which imports all other components.
In some of them, I need to use the `makeUrl()` function I defined.
But I can't import `routes.js` because it will create a cyclic import.

I can't move my `makeUrl()` function in another module because I need the access the Vue-router instance, so I'll have to import `routes.js` in this another modules => circular import again.

So, I heard of `$router` variable, so I tried to build a utility component which contains a `makeUrl()` function :

```
//util-component.js
'use strict';

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue';

const UtilComponent = Vue.component('util-component', {
  methods: {
      makeUrl(url){
          return this.$router.base + url;
      }
  }
});

export default UtilComponent;
```

And in my personal component :

```
//my-component.vue
<template>
    <img class="logo" :src="util.makeUrl('/assets/img/logo-transp.svg')" alt=""/>        
</template>

<script>

import util from 'utils/util-component';

export default {
  data () { return {};}
}
</script>
```

But with this it end with the same `TypeError: e.makeUrl is not a function`... :(

How can I deal with it ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can't you `export {router};`?

Comment: It end to the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your utility functions you should use a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) instead:

```
// mixins/Utils.js
export default {
  methods: {
    makeUrl(url) {
      return this.$router.options.base + url;
    }
  }
}
```

You can add the mixin to your component like this:

```
<script>
import Utils from 'mixins/Utils';

export default {
  mixins: [ Utils ],
}
</script>
```

Now, your component has a `makeUrl` method which will be called within its scope, meaning its reference to `this.$router` will be the `VueRouter` instance you want.

You can use this method in your template like any other component method:

```
<template>
  <img class="logo" :src="makeUrl('/assets/img/logo-transp.svg')" alt=""/>        
</template>
```

Comment: Oh yes it works well ! Thank you !

PS : I must do `return this.$router.options.base + url;` in my mixin